# How can I remove the exceeding parts in the buildings in this image?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, graph-algorithm, opencv3.0

[original unfiltered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMqj4.jpg)I have a problem with the detected areas of the rooftops in this image. I already made dilation and open morphological operations and this is the best result I got.
Any ideas on how can I optimize the areas and remove the exceeding parts??
Thanks in advance.
The approach I used was as follows:
1-shadow masking and vegetation masking were done first
2- Gaussian blur and mean-shift segmentation followed by K-means clustering
3- connected components algorithm to produce regions for pixels with similar spectral properties. but the sidewalk and footpaths were segmented together with the rooftops so I used the dilation and open morphological transformation to separate them as best as I could and applied SVM to detect the rooftops in the end but the results were not very good as shown in the attached image: areas of the facade were included together with the areas of the roofs in some buildings.

[Buildings with exceeding parts in the areas of rooftops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuEOZ.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65482477/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How do you know that they are "exceeding" ? Can you express it in an objective way ?

Comment: Preferably with a textual explanation of what you did and the rationale behind it (and optionally code).

Comment: I guess whatever he does to segment rooftops also catches pixels that aren't rooftop (but sidewalk, road, side of house, ...) the way to solve this is review his approach, but he needs to post that first.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The purpose is to detect the areas of the rooftops in the provided image, the approach I used was as follows:
1-shadow masking and vegetation masking were done first
2- Gaussian blur and mean-shift segmentation followed by K-means clustering
3- connected components algorithm to produce regions for pixels with similar spectral properties. but the sidewalk and footpaths were segmented together with the rooftops so I used the dilation and open morphological transformation to separate them as best as I could and applied SVM to detect the rooftops in the end but the results were bad

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You're right, the sidewalk and footpaths were segmented together with the rooftops due to similar spectral properties.
I used machine learning (SVM) to detect the buildings only using 5 features that mainly included areas, mean grey level for the rooftops provided in a training dataset I prepared for the SVM.

Comment: Image processing algorithms don't know what rooftops and vegetation are.

Comment: it would be a good idea to ALWAYS post UNFILTERED source data along with what you already posted. also, this segmentation problem is likely solved best using DNNs (as is often the case these days). it's more complicated but potentially gives better results.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know, I've done the segmentation based on k-means that depends on mean grey level.. the problem is that I want to improve the results by getting accurate roof areas without using for NN.

Comment: You can explain for days what functions you used, the problem is that you need to objectivate what a roof is vs. vegetation. I am not even sure that a human could solve your problem the way you like.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I know it's complicated and the idea of the study was to use SVM without using NN. That's why the results are not very accurate. (I posted the original image).

Comment: @YvesDaoust what do you suggest I do?

Comment: To objectivate what is a roof vs. vegetation.

Comment: this sounds like a thesis topic, and too broad a problem for a question on Stack Overflow. I don't expect SVM will solve this. this needs convolutional neural networks that learn building appearance from examples. there is no simpler formulation for "roof".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You're right. Actually, it's my MSC thesis and this is the last part that I'm stuck at.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I tried to do it by preparing the training dataset with 5 features (area, mean grey level, roundness, major_minor ratio,...etc.) for buildings and non-buildings. Guess that does not work out well.

Comment: you need to talk to your thesis advisor. you probably do something wrong very early. my bet is you're filtering the image or processing it into something that loses vital information.